# Connecting AC to DC floating ground

Tags: analog

I'm trying to convert AC sin wave that comes from tacho coil into DC square wave and i found this scheme:
[image: wave converter]

Can floating ground coming from DC power supply be used with this scheme?

Comment: Are you referring to the 5 V supply? The ground on the 5 V supply has to be the same as the Tacho ground.  Also, you may want to check your tach frequency range and possibly adjust R1 and C1 if needed.

Comment: @JohnD Yes, 5V and GNDD are coming from the same power supply. So its fine to connect them even if its floating ground? 

Also as a side question, i connected one end of tacho to DC ground and second one to osciloscope proble and probe ground to the same DC ground and my scope showed 300V wave (and i could feel tingling when touching probe ground clip and DC ground) while 5V wasnt even connected to anything and tacho wasnt used, how is this possible?

Comment: At this point you should probably add a diagram and picture of your setup showing where you're probing and what's hooked to what.  Otherwise it's hard to guess at what's going on.  Not sure what your concern is about the "floating" ground, if you hook it to a chassis or other reference point it will no longer be floating.

Comment: What voltage and frequency is the input to TACHO

Comment: @JohnD It looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/7BND64t.png

Comment: @VoltageSpike There are not inputs to TACHO. It only outputs sin wave when motor is rotating (motor wasnt even connected when i got 300V readings).

Comment: In the circuit above TACHO is an input

Comment: @VoltageSpike The one from question or link that i posted?

Comment: The one in the question. When I asked the question you had not posted the link

Comment: @VoltageSpike It wasnt connected like that when i was probing since i wanted to see what's changing after each component is added. This circuit was only relevant to question about connecting DC ground to TACHO output.

Answer (score 0):

No a floating scheme cannot be used. The circuit input must be referenced to ground, otherwise the circuit cannot detect the correct voltage as it will be floating.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit input must be referenced to circuit common, which is not necessarily earth ground. Circuit common for this circuit is "GNDD", and it must be connected to the 5V supply return and whatever the output D3 is referenced to.

Comment: So if i'm powering this circuit through battery, will it work correctly assuming GND will be connected to (-)?

Comment: @Alkyone That's how battery-powered devices with a negative common (most of them) work.